# -webkit-box-reflect - CSS for FireFox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to do someting like this **http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/HoverEffects/Ex5.html**, where the reflection of the image shows under , however it doesnt work on IE or FireFox.  here is my code that I have http://jsfiddle.net/srvcm/1/ Is there any trick to make firefox to do this?

```
 .ex img {
        <!--margin: 25px;-->
        opacity: 0.9;
        border: 1px solid #eee;

        /*Transition*/
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;

        /*Reflection*/
        -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(.7, transparent), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.1)));


    }


    .ex img:hover {  
       opacity: 1;

       /*Reflection*/
      -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(.7, transparent), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.7)));

       /*Glow*/
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you even try googling CSS3 reflection? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/css3-reflection-effect

Comment: YEs I have, A lot of people say it doesnt work on FireFox

Comment: Sorry, I have cancelled my downvote (it was a unnecessary). The link above should show you how to achieve the effect cross browser (although it doesn't use `box-reflect`)

Comment: I saw your link , and thank you for showing the link to me. I am just wondering, can I mix the FirFox version of CSS style with my Classes? Like can I merge them together or do they have to be separate

Comment: You can mix things if you use the vendor prefixes (probably not the best idea) and you could also add particular CSS by targeting individual browsers. However, if it were up to me, I would use the most widely supported approach and then add the new stuff when it is more established

Comment: okay thanx; Ill just leave it as is for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/#search=box-ref  <- cross-browsers compatability's seem to be lacking for that property

Comment: Ya,Thank you Mods for your link. do you think, there is like JavaScript for this kind of effects? Do you know what they call it

Comment: Its a little drastic but if you absolutely have to change around your code completely because you want to keep a similar effect, This would work (note, you would have to have a flipped version of the photo or use some sort of property etc to flip the picture at the bottom)
http://jsfiddle.net/srvcm/9/

Comment: Pursuing this method you would also need a conditional statement, To either dictate "If Chrome skip these" For the code i added,  Or having 2 css files and having a conditional comment "if chrome use this css" Else Use This css. Im no expert so keep looking might be a easier way of achieving.

Comment: Thank you sir, I ll just gono skip on it, and let it be

Comment: I saw that one, its hard to do, I am not an expert, I cant do that much coding